# Code Coverage is including system.debug and comments too

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a weird situation, in one of my class code coverage is calculated including system.debug statements and comments too. Any clue what might be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes your code coverage will be out of sync with the source. The reason for this is unknown, but fixing it is usually as simple as using `Clear Code Coverage` and then using `Run All Tests`.

Comment: This has always frustrated me.  Didn't know there was a such an easy potential work around! :)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen before when you've run tests multiple times. I think it is getting confused with previous test runs. Try clearing out your test history and running the test again.

Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution > View Test History and click 'Clear Test Results'

Comment: Thank you.. I cleared code coverage and the issue disappeared.